# How can I convert vectors into JSON and then post it in a service

Tags: arrays, r, json, multidimensional-array, vector

I need to convert this two vectors into a JSON with some other fields:

```
x_axis <- c("Dogs","Cats","Birds")
y_axis <- c(5,9,3)
```

The JSON must also contain these two fields:

```
user_id=3
model_number=4
```

The JSON to post must have this format:

```
{
    "user_id":3,
    "model_number": 4,
    "data": [{
      "x_axis": "Dogs",
      "y_axis": 5
  },{
      "x_axis": "Cats",
      "y_axis": 9
  },{
      "x_axis": "Birds",
      "y_axis": 3
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jsonlite`...

```
library(jsonlite)
x_axis <- c("Dogs","Cats","Birds")
y_axis <- c(5,9,3)
user_id=3
model_number=4

data <- data.frame(x_axis=x_axis,y_axis=y_axis)

toJSON(list(user_id=user_id,
            model_number=model_number,
            data=data),
       dataframe="rows",
       auto_unbox = TRUE)

{"user_id":3,
 "model_number":4,
 "data":[{"x_axis":"Dogs","y_axis":5},
         {"x_axis":"Cats","y_axis":9},
         {"x_axis":"Birds","y_axis":3}]}
```

Comment: This works great, but how can I avoid de brackets around the user_id value?, must be only the number

Comment: @Idle Man: You need to add the `auto_unbox = TRUE` flag to toJSON function.

Comment: @IdleMan Thanks - I was wondering about that! I've updated the answer above

Answer (score 0):

You can create that output using `purrr` and `jsonlite`

```
library(purrr)
library(jsonlite)
toJSON(list(
  user_id = user_id,
  model_number = model_number,
  data = map2(x_axis, y_axis, ~list(x_axis=.x, y_axis=.y))
), auto_unbox = TRUE)
```

Basically we just create a named list in such a way that mirrors your desired output shape. Named lists result in `{}` objects and unnamed lists become `[]` arrays.